# Laravel PHP: Eloquent Repository does not recognize model

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm having a problem with an Eloquent Repository that I've created where it's not recognizing the model for the data I'm trying to collect from my form.  I even copied my model into the Eloquent Repository's namespace but it's still not being recognized.

**Eloquent Repository** (app\Acme\repositories\Eloquent\EloquentVideoRepository.php):

```
<?php namespace Acme\repositories\Eloquent;

use acme\repositories\VideoRepository;

/* Tried copying the 'Video' model into the same
   namespace as this Eloquent Repository but it is not being recognized. */

use acme\repositories\Video;

class EloquentVideoRepository implements VideoRepository {

   public function all()
   {
      return Video::all();
   }

  /* This function below generates an error since the 'Video' class 
     is not found from my 'Video' Model */

   public function create($input)
   {
    return Video::create($input);
   }
}
```

**Model(app\models\Video.php):**

```
<?php

 /* Original Line of code below that generated the error: 

 class Video extends Eloquent 
 */

/* EDIT:  I put a backslash in front of Eloquent
and now the model is recognized. 
*/
class Video extends \Eloquent {

/**
 * The table used by this model
 *
 * @var string
 **/
protected $table = 'videos';

/**
 * The primary key
 *
 * @var string
 **/
protected $primaryKey = 'video_id';

/**
 * The fields that are guarded cannot be mass assigned
 *
 * @var array
 **/
protected $guarded = array();

/**
*  Enabling soft deleting
*
*  @var boolean
**/
 protected $softDelete = true;

}
```

I've also copied the Model above to 'app\acme\repositories'.

**Error Message that is displayed:**

```
'Class acme\repositories\Video not found'
```

I've tried perform php artisan dump-autoload even after copying the model into this namespace but it's still not working.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show the head of your Video class file including it's name and namespace plz. Also show the exact error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Video class file is missing any namespace declaration and therefore is in the default namespace. Extending something does not change it's namespace.

Add this line on top to add it itno your desired namespace:

```
namespace Acme\repositories\Eloquent;
```

Or add a use line as below to your other file, but **I doubt that is what you want**:

```
use \Video;
```

Comment: I tried using your suggestion but the model is still not being recognized.  I'm going to try a few experiments and keep you posted.

Comment: Ok I found a solution.  It was a combination of 2 things:  1) Using the namespace as you mentioned above.  2)  I had my 'Video.php' model class originally defined as 'class Video extends Eloquent', so I put a backslash in front of 'Eloquent' and now my Eloquent Repository recognizes the model.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you sure the Eloquent class is in the default namespace? This seems a bit odd.

Comment: I'm not really sure but for now my application isn't generating an error with trying to find my model.  I'll keep you posted if I run into any issues later on.

Comment: So throughout the afternoon I've been testing out my Eloquent Repository and it's actually been working fine even with the '\Eloquent' declaration.  I really appreciate your help ToBe, thank you!